# Qt/C++: 'undefined reference to __imp__ZN5Enemy16staticMetaObjectE' when building project on Windows with MinGW

Tags: qt, build, undefined-reference, moc

It is my first post here so please ask for any extra info you need!
I have to make this game in Qt with a given source code to start from: world.h & world.cpp
[Given code class example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN9fV.png)

Now when I build the project I get this error for every class & its functions defined in these files (29 similar errors):

**ERROR:**
:-1: error: debug/moc_world.o: in function `Enemy::metaObject() const': team-c4-fa\build-PanicGame-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\moc_world.cpp:129: error: **undefined reference to` __imp__ZN5Enemy16staticMetaObjectE'**
:-1: error: debug/moc_world.o: in function `Enemy::dead()':                       team-c4-fa\build-PanicGame-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\moc_world.cpp:162: error: undefined reference to` __imp__ZN5Enemy16staticMetaObjectE'
:-1: error: debug/moc_world.o: in function `PEnemy::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':                                          team-c4-fa\build-PanicGame-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\moc_world.cpp:257: error: undefined reference to` __imp__ZN6PEnemy6poisonEv'[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIxxz.png)

I suspect that this error has something to do with the way my build directory is setup, it gives me the warning of : “The build directory should be at the same level as the source directory.”
I can’t seem to change this by restructuring the hierarchy.[warning build directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iusM.png)

**EXTRA:**
I have two warnings and an error before all these similar errors:
team-c4-fa\build-PanicGame-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug:1494: warning: overriding recipe for target 'debug/world.o'
team-c4-fa\build-PanicGame-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug:1491: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'debug/world.o'
:-1: error: debug/game.o: in function `Game::loadWorld(QString)':

First I thought something was wrong with the "linking" (that was what chat gpt said). So I tried recreating the troubled classes & cleaning the project and rebuilding it, not sure what exactly I was doing

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This is a common problem. Google for the error message (or google better). In short, you need to use Q_OBJECT macro. Then you need to re-run cmake/qmake for that to take effect.